# Django Test Case Can't run method

Tags: python, django, testing

I am just getting started with Django, so this may be something stupid, but I am not even sure what to google at this point.

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def get_user(self,user):
    return Utilities.get_userprofile(user)
```

The method looks like this:

```
@staticmethod
def get_userprofile(user):
    return UserProfile.objects.filter(user_auth__username=user)[0]
```

When I include this in the view, everything is fine. When I write a test case to use any of the methods inside the Utility class, I get None back:

Two test cases:

```
def test_stack_overflow(self):
    a = ObjName()
    print(a.get_user('admin'))

def test_Utility(self):
    print(Utilities.get_user('admin'))
```

Results:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
None
..None
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can someone tell me why this is working in the view, but not working inside of the test case and does not generate any error messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Verify whether your unit test comply the followings,

1. `TestClass` must be written in a file name `test*.py`
2. `TestClass` must have been subclassed from [unittest.TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)
3. `TestClass` should have a `setUp` function to create objects(usually done in this way, but objects creation can happen in the test functions as well) in the database
4. `TestClass` functions should start with `test` so as to be identified and run by the `./manage.py` test command
5. `TestClass` may have `tearDown` to properly end the unit test case.

Test Case Execution process:

When you run `./manage.py test` django sets up a `test_your_database_name` and creates all the objects mentioned in the `setUp` function(Usually) and starts executing the test functions in the order of placement inside the class and once when all the test functions are executed, finally looks for the `tearDown` function executes if any present in the test class and destroys the test database.

It **may be** because that you might not have invoked objects creation in setUp function or elsewhere in the `TestClass`.

Can you kindly post the entire traceback and test file to help you better?

Comment: Hey, the last bit you mentioned may be it! The method gets the user object by username and if there is a brand new database, then it will obviously not pull in anything. I think I will need to create a few objects before starting tests to make sure it's valid.

Comment: I definitely will; let me verify it first :) How is this usually handled? Do you have a method in the test cases that sets up some items in the database?

Comment: Setting up data in the database e.g `Models.objects.create(**kwargs)` can be usually handled in the `setUp` function in your TestClass you can refer [Django - Writing and running tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests)